# More info about save in GORM

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm

I have a simple block of code, that return false

```
PromoDebit promoDebit = new PromoDebit();
            promoDebit.promoCode=promoCode;
            promoDebit.userId=userId;
            promoDebit.countUsages=countUsages;
            promoDebit.endDate=endDate;
            promoDebit.startDate=startDate;
            promoDebit.status=1;
            promoDebit.calcValue=Float.parseFloat(p.getProperty("promoPercent"));
             if(promoDebit.save(flush: true)){
                 log.info "GOOD!"
            } else {
                 log.info "BAD!"
             }
```

How can I get more info about GORM.save fail? Stdrout log show nothning even if I turn on logSql in DataSource.groovy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## First ,make sure that your Log4j is configured correctly.

Here http://grails.org/doc/2.3.1/guide/conf.html#logging

And ,If you wan to know more detail info on GORM.save fail like

```
        PromoDebit promoDebit = new PromoDebit();
        promoDebit.promoCode=promoCode;
        promoDebit.userId=userId;
        promoDebit.countUsages=countUsages;
        promoDebit.endDate=endDate;
        promoDebit.startDate=startDate;
        promoDebit.status=1;
        promoDebit.calcValue=Float.parseFloat(p.getProperty("promoPercent"));
```

Then ,

```
if (!promoDebit.save()) {
   log.warn myDomainObj.errors.allErrors.join(' \n') 
   //each error is an instance of  org.springframework.validation.FieldError    
}
```

And , I like this one

```
if (!promoDebit.save()) {
    promoDebit.errors.each {
        println it
    }
}
```

If you want to throw an exception for EVERY domain classes, then simply set `grails.gorm.failOnError to true in grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`

or Simply

```
promoDebit.save(failOnError:true)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
log.warn "error occurred by saving: $promoDebit.errors"
```

you will see the validation failures in the log. If some SQL-constraint gets broken you will get a full-blown `Exception` like `DataIntegrityException`